# I'm unable to install AMD drivers on a laptop

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, radeon

(Keep in mind, I just started using Ubuntu a few hours ago)

I am currently trying to install AMD APU drivers ([Click Here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-series-processors/amd-a8-series-apu-for-laptops/a8-4500m-radeon-hd-7640g)) (64-bit)

It just says that I'm missing the following dependencies, then it doesn't list them.

I'm using 20.04.2.0 LTS

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you shouldn't use fglrx which seems to be unmaintained. The link you provided contains drivers for very old Ubuntu (7/9 years ago) and will never work on newer Ubuntu version.

Do you have something wrong with the Open Source drivers? You might need to install additional drivers with the following process.
https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/

Comment: When I follow the guide, the additional drivers page shows nothing at all.